# Limited GROUP_CONCAT with LEFT JOIN and IF statement

Tags: mysql, left-join, substring, group-concat, csv

I have 3 tables in MySQL

`fruit`

```
id| fruit
--+-------
1 | apple
2 | banana
3 | mango
4 | plum
5 | pear
6 | cherry
```

`list`

```
id| name
--+------------
1 | first list
2 | second list
```

`list_content`

```
id| list_id | fruit_id | active
--+---------+----------+-------
1 |1        |1         |1
2 |1        |2         |1
3 |1        |3         |1
4 |2        |1         |0
5 |2        |6         |1
6 |2        |5         |1
7 |2        |4         |1
8 |2        |3         |1
```

As a result I need a list ordered by `id` in descending order with maximum 3 comma separated active elements (if `active` = 1) ordered by `fruit.name` in ascending order. Like this

```
lists  | fruits
-------+------------------
list 2 | cherry, mango, pear
list 1 | apple, banana, mango
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to get only the first 3 fruits.

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(IF(active = 1, fruit.name, null) ORDER BY fruit.name ASC),',',3)
```

Comment: And how can I infiltrate IF statement in query?

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` ignores `null`'s so you can put it there, but it will be better if you can put it in your WHERE/ON clause.